# Two column fluid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website with two column CSS, using left column for main content and right column for sidebar. I  see how it work on front end, but try to replicate on the second platform, it didn't work.

**Main content CSS:**

```
#main-content { float: none; width: 100%; margin-left:0; }
```

**Sidebar CSS:**

```
#sidebar { width:230px; position:relative; float:right; border-left: 1px #eee solid; }
```

but the sidebar is not flowing down when resized to smaller screen.

For example on my front layout the side flow down under the main content after i resize the screen to be smaller. Here is the
[**layout example**](http://rv5.com/the-dali-museum-events-get-drawn-in-to-mc-escher) but when i try to resize on layout 2 for the new platform, it doesn't flow down. Can someone help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It does flow down, for me, unless I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: this is layout 2.. trying to achieve the same layout as the link above...http://rv5.com/layout2/